# Most efficient way to login when multiple tables exist

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

I was using a registration form for teachers and one for students. There are ten fields in each, first name, last name, username, password, etc being similar whereas departments (teachers have 7, students have 3) and email ids (teachers have a different domain extension and students different) being different. I am using two tables, one for teachers and one for student.

Now, I know I can use one login form, query against these two tables using the JOIN property and make them login. But I want to know if this method is efficient because two tables are being used.

Or is this method more efficient: In the reg form, I put a radio button to select teacher or student and depending on what one chooses the remaining fields change, i.e, if I choose teacher, 7 departments show up or if I choose student only 3 of them show up. In this way, I have to use one table only, atleast I guess so.

Or another possibility is I use two tables but two login forms, one for teacher and one for student, I know this is the easy way out but being a Comp Sci student I want to choose the efficient method of all.

P.S: The teacher's role is going to be completely different from the student's in the site. And there will be lot of activities for the teachers and students, they are completely different. Will maintaining one table be a good bet?

Comment: How are you storing departments? Could you show the `DESCRIBE` output of both tables you have now?

Comment: I am planning to store them by fetching dropdown values. The tables I have right now are pretty ordinary, made with phpmyadmin. I am going to design the login and register thing now, so I need to know the most efficient way so that I can go ahead design it and come back to you all with further doubts if I have. But still if you want a sample look, let me know, I will show you one!

Comment: http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/5581/scr3o.png   The student table is also similar. Department values will be fetched from the dropdown options chosen. A teacher gets to choose from a pool of 7 options, a student gets to choose from a pool of 3.

Comment: You should better consider using `UNION` instead of `JOIN`

Comment: Yeah, UNION is a handy one if I use two tables. But these guys sorted out my problem and helped me do it with one table itself. But still thank you Benjamin, I will keep your suggestion in mind if I have any such problems in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that both teachers and students are users, but teachers have higher privileges, much like an administrator.

As such, I would only use 1 table for `users` and have an attribute column to indicate what type they are.

Once they login, you can return a type variable to your page to determine what fields to display.

And you really don't even need a radio button to indicate the type. Just have a username and password field. Then once they are authenticated, retrieve the type attribute and load your form accordingly.

Your PHP page might look like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE userid=" . $user;

        //Execute SQL
        if($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
            if ($password == $row['password']) {
                $userType = $row['type'];
                $mysqli->close();
                echo $userType;
            else { echo "incorrect password"; }

        } else { echo "SQL execution error"; }
    } else { 
        echo "invalid username string"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: So you mean, use one table, and based on teacher or student load the form accordingly. But how can I differentiate between both of them without a radio button or a dropdown?

Comment: Theyre mutually exclusive right? Each person can only be either a teacher OR a student, correct? If so, retrieve the record from the user table for the provided username, verify their password, then return to your page a variable indicating if they are a student or a teacher.

Comment: Yes,they are mutually exclusive. Yeah, I get your point. I am just asking, in the reg field how do I ask them to specify if they are a teacher or a student because you said no need of a radio button. Also, I've told you 2 fields will be different for them. Example, a student needs to sign up with emailid@univstu.com and a teacher needs to sign up using emailid@univteach.com! That's how my dept people want the sign up to be!

Comment: Okay, I kind of got what you said. Thank You. I will try this and get back to you if I have any more problems :)

Comment: Yes, I tried this and I got it working but new demands forced me to use two tables, two reg forms and two sign ups. Your answer helped me gained some knowledge and that's more important :) Thanks a ton!